# Continuous Deployment using Jenkins and Opswork integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-opsworks

I am trying to setup Continuous deployment using jenkins and OpsWorks. I have configured Jenkins but I dont know how to integrate Jenkins with OpsWorks to auto deploy using Chef Cookbook.
Is there any plugin available for OpsWorks and Jenkins integration?(I think there is no plugin available from AWS. I dont know why....).

Can I have some steps/suggestoins to write chef cookbook to integrate OpsWorks with Jenkins?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is way too broad. Please search the web for getting started and ask detail questions, if you encounter a specific problem.

Answer (score 4):

I do this by calling the CLI tool in a Jenkins project. Something like this:

```
aws opsworks --region us-east-1 create-deployment --stack-id <your id> --app-id <your app id> --command "{\"Name\":\"deploy\"}"
```

You can find the IDs in your stack configuration.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do continuous deployment then you can use AWS CodeDeploy also instead of Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

You can now integrate OpsWorks into a CodePipeline:
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/06/aws-codepipeline-adds-integration-with-aws-opsworks/

> This lets you automate the release of updated application code and Chef cookbooks to your applications and instances running in OpsWorks.

This allows you to implement CD into your OpsWorks stack, with or without Jenkins.

Comment: This is currently only available for us-east-1 region

Comment: Codepipeline is available now in all regions : https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regional-product-services/

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI while that's true for CodePipeline itself, you can only select OpsWorks Stacks as a deployment target when in the us-east-1 region.